# Application-Managed entityManager work, but Container-Managed Entity Manager doesn't. Why?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, jta

I develop client-server application with JavaEE. I have a stateless bean **AuthenticateEJB**.
It works fine, database entry refreshs when I use *Application-Managed Entity Manager* (package and import statements omitted for simplifying):

```
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "horses_unit")
    EntityManager em;
                user.setToken("PapaToken");
                EntityManagerFactory emf =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("horses_unit");
                EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
                EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
                tx.begin();
                   em.merge(user);
                tx.commit();
                em.close();
                emf.close();
```

but nothing happens when I use *Container-Managed Entity Manager*:

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ForthDynamicWebProject")
    EntityManager em;
                user.setToken("PapaToken");
                em.merge(user);
```

Here is my **persistence.xml** file (some code omitted for simplifying):

```
<persistence-unit name="horses_unit" transaction-type = "RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<persistence-unit name="ForthDynamicWebProject" transaction-type = "JTA">
```

Why I can't write to database with Container-Managed Entity Manager? Where do I make mistakes?

Comment: @BalusC It is not duplicate, please look at my persistence.xml file. There are two different persistence-units:  for RESOURCE_LOCAL and for JTA transaction types.

Comment: @BalusC I've reworked it. Any suggestions?